# scikit learn loading raw documents

Tags: python, scikit-learn

How do i use this api to load multiple text files?

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.datasets import load_files

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(files)
print(vectorizer.get_feature_names_out())
```

I expect the following (where txt is a folder of txt files) to give me the right input?

`files = load_files('./input/txt')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`load_files()` function uses the following directory structure to get files:

```
container_folder/
    category_1_folder/
        file_1.txt file_2.txt … file_42.txt
    category_2_folder/
        file_43.txt file_44.txt …
```

in your case you only have one subfolder. So you need to put just input folder in the load_files function.

Example:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.datasets import load_files

files = load_files("input/",load_content=True)

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(files['data'])
```